# Using MySQL dynamically, without table

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use MySQL dynamically to achieve something like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x FROM ('aaa', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'ccc') x;
```

where the part `'aaa', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'ccc'` **represents a comma separated list of 1000000 values** (*not table names, not column names*) (sorry for confusion).

### So all I can do is copy and paste this comma separated list.

### **I cannot wrap UNIONs around all values.**

Expected output:

```
x
------
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Why not use command line tools?

I like MySQL for its syntax on how to manipulate data, GROUPING, SORTING, ... MySQL is the best and easiest to handle datasets.

Again:

A list is defined as:

```
'aaaa',
'bbbbb',
'aabb',
'ffff',
'dfdff',
'aabb',
'ddsss'
[+ 1000 of those lines]
```

Now I want to copy and paste this list and do MySQL operations to it. Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [paste list here];
```

Or:

SELECT * FROM [paste list here] WHERE value LIKE 'aaa%'

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.x 
FROM 
(SELECT 'aaa' AS x
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bbb'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'aaa'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ccc') a
```

Would result in

```
|   X |
|-----|
| aaa |
| bbb |
| ccc |
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/27341)

If you have many values, then you should load them into a temporary table and run a `DISTINCT` on the temp table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] listOfValues (
    value varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO listOfValues (value)
('aaa'),
('bbb'),
('aaa'),
('ccc');

SELECT DISTINCT value FROM listOfValues;
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on your updated question, you can create a temporary table, use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) (there's a [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605765/importing-a-csv-into-mysql-via-command-line) option as well) and lastly run a `DISTINCT` on the rows. There's no way to *"copy & paste"* it, unless you want to put it in a blob or long text and write a parser which goes beyond what MySQL was designed for.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 'aaa'
UNION
SELECT 'bbb'
UNION 
SELECT 'aaa'
UNION 
SELECT 'ccc'
```

Will work

Union will remove the duplicates, Union all keeps duplicates 
With wanting to work with so many values maybe look here

[remove dups from many csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888748/remove-dups-from-many-csv-files)

Unless theres some reason it actually needs to be solved in SQL

Comment: @user1281385 OP has yet to provide a valid reason why this needs to be solved using MySQL.

Comment: We have both given the if yes hows, You could use the CSV engine too